# How to insert other language's numbers in an integer text field?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have an Integer Text Field which I want to fill with numbers in Persian (as long as the whole content fields should be filled with Persian characters), but when I write numbers when my keyboard is in Persian mode, Drupal doesn't detect the numbers and replies "Only numbers are allowed in Pages". And of course I prefer not to change keyboard mode every time to fill this field.

what should I do to solve this problem?
I'm using Drupal 7 on my local machine.
Thanks.